# Resize ajax.org ACE editor based on browser's size

Tags: ace-editor

I want to let the ACE editor to be resizable based on the browser's 
size. however, the editor element must be explicitly sized in order to 
be initialized by the ace editor's API.

The editor works when I set the width:100%/height:400px. Having this setting allows the editor 's width responsive to the browser's width. However, not responsive for the editor's height.

Is there a way to make the editor's size more flexible by responding to browser's size?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

```js
function resizeAce() {
  return $('#editor').height($(window).height());
};
//listen for changes
$(window).resize(resizeAce);
//set initially
resizeAce();
```

Answer (score 4):

set `position:absolute;top:0; bottom:0`
like https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/editor.html#L14

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on jpillora's excellent guidance:

```
function resizeAce() {
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    if (h > 360) {
        $('#editor').css('height', (h - 290).toString() + 'px');
    }
};
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    resizeAce();
});
resizeAce();
```

`window.innerHeight` is supported by IE8+ and seems reliable for getting the usable area of the screen. I ended up with identical results on IE9, FF, and Chrome. I also found that I had to use the jQuery `on` syntax to reliably catch the window resize event.

I needed to use jQuery `css` because in my case I'm resizing a `pre` element (that shows coding help) that sits to the right of the code editor, and this was the only way to get the two elements to exactly the same height.

The `360` and `290` are the numbers I needed to use to account for all the menus and tabs taking up vertical space at the top of my page. Adjust accordingly.